# Replay tic tac toe game

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, do-while, tic-tac-toe

So I am trying to program a way to replay a tic tac toe game after someone wins, loses, or ties.
So basically my attempt to get replay to work, doesnt work. If player 1 won and I type 1 to replay, it would ask player 2 for their input.

Pseudocode outline:

```
do {
  set entire 2d array to '*'
  do {
    player 1 input
    does game tie?
    does player 1 win
    player 2 input
    does game tie?
    does player 2 win
  } while no one wins
} while replay = 1
```

My actual code:

```
//tie check, replay, use pointer notation
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void initialize(char [][3]);
void player1(char [][3]);
void player2(char [][3]);
void display(char [][3]);
char check(char [3][3]);
int checkWin(int);
int tie(int);
int askReplay();
int main()
{
    char board[3][3];
    char end = '*';
    int row1, column1, row2,column2;
    int replay = 0;
    int turns = 0;
    //replay loop
    do {
        //set board to *
        initialize(board);
        display(board);
        do {
            //player 1 turn
            player1(board);
            turns++;
            display(board);

            //if turns = 9 then tie
            replay = tie(turns);
            //check if player 1 won
            end = check(board);
            replay = checkWin(end);

            //player 2 turn
            player2(board);
            turns++;
            display(board);

            //if turns = 9 then tie
            replay = tie(turns);
            //check if player 2 won
            end = check(board);
            replay = checkWin(end);

        } while (end == '*');
    } while (replay == 1);
    return 0;
}

void initialize(char (*array)[3])
{
    for (int i = 0;i < 3;i++)
        for (int j = 0;j < 3;j++)
            array[i][j] = '*';
    cout << "New Game\n";
}

void player1(char (*array)[3])
{
    int row1, column1;
    cout << "Player 1\nRow: ";
    cin >> row1;
    while (row1 < 0 || row1 > 2) {
        cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 2 for Row:: ";
        cin >> row1;
    }

    cout << "Column: ";
    cin >> column1;
    while (column1 < 0 || column1 > 2) {
        cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 2 for Column: ";
        cin >> column1;
    }

    if (array[row1][column1] == '*')
        array[row1][column1] = 'X';
    else {
        cout << "Space Occupied\n";
        player1(array);
    }
}

void player2(char (*array)[3])
{
    int row2,column2;
    cout << "Player 2\nRow: ";
    cin >> row2;
    while (row2 < 0 || row2 > 2) {
        cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 2 for Row: ";
        cin >> row2;
    }

    cout << "Column: ";
    cin >> column2;
    while (column2 < 0 || column2 > 2) {
        cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 2 for Column: ";
        cin >> column2;
    }

    if (array[row2][column2] == '*')
        array[row2][column2] = 'O';
    else {
        cout << "Space Occupied\n";
        player2(array);
    }
}

void display(char (*array)[3])
{
    for (int x = 0;x < 3;x++) {
        for (int y = 0;y < 3;y++)
            cout << *(*(array + x) + y) << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

char check(char (*array)[3])
{
    int i;

    /* check rows */
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    if(array[i][0] == array[i][1] && array[i][0] == array[i][2])
        return array[i][0];

    /* check columns */
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        if(array[0][i] == array[1][i] && array[0][i] == array[2][i])
            return array[0][i];

    /* test diagonals */
    if(array[0][0] == array[1][1] && array[1][1] == array[2][2])
        return array[0][0];

    if(array[0][2] == array[1][1] && array[1][1] == array[2][0])
        return array[0][2];
    return '*';
}

int checkWin(int over)
{
    if (over == '*')
        return 0;
    if (over == 'X')
        cout << "Player 1 Won!\n";
    else if (over == 'O')
        cout << "Player 2 Won!\n";

    //ask if they want to play again
    int answer;
    answer = askReplay();

    switch (answer) {
    case 1:
        return 1;
    case 2:
        cout << "Thank you for playing.\n";
        exit(0);
    }
}

int tie(int count)
{
    if (count == 9) {
        int answer;
        cout << "Tie game";

        answer = askReplay();

        switch (answer) {
        case 1:
            return 1;
        case 2:
            cout << "Thank you for playing.\n";
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}

int askReplay()
{
    int input;
    do {
        cout << "Play Again?\n1.Yes\n2.No\nEnter 1 or 2: ";
        cin >> input;
        if (input > 2 || input < 1)
            cout << "Invalid Option\n";
    } while(input > 2 || input < 1);

    return input;
}
```

Comment: This is not jeopardy, you got phrase your `question` in the form of a question ;-)

Comment: I cannot answer if there is not any question. Sorry.

Comment: My replay doesnt work, If player 1 won and I type 1 to replay, it would ask player 2 for their input

Comment: Yes it's snarky, but...  When did StackOverflow become "Please help me with my programming homework"?

Comment: Oh I don't know, since SO was created? It's a place for programmers to get help, new or experienced. Quite the high horse you guys are riding, I wish I never had to ask for help.

Comment: There's asking for help with specific issues, then there's doing a code dump and saying "Why doesn't this work?"

Comment: You mean "play again" (start a new game), and not "replay" (repeat the moves of the game just played in order to review them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're having troubles with your main loop.

I'd suggest making a variable that controls which player is running and just toggle that.

```
do  
{    
  set entire 2d array to '*'  
  current player = 0
  do  
  {  
    (current player + 1) input  
    does game tie?  
    does (current player + 1) win

    current player = (current player + 1) % 2  
  }while no one wins     
}while replay = 1
```

See if that gets you further along.

Comment: +1.  This will simplify the code significantly.  It also makes sense to merge the `player1` and `player` functions (adding an argument to indicate which player is moving).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look up the Memento Design Pattern.

Comment: This is way overkill for the OP's purposes.  The OP isn't even defining classes to store game state.

Comment: I guess I read replay to mean replay the entire game step by step (as in instant-replay). I guess the OP meant replay to play again. I think you'll find the question was edited after my response.